# Liferay Portal Activiti Integration

Tags: liferay, workflow, portlet, activiti

This question has been asked and answered in past, but none of the solutions work for me, may be because liferay and activiti have changed drastically since then, or may be because of the fact that the answers were not sufficiently clear to me to be helpful.

I am just starting with Liferay and Activiti.

The target Liferay Portal Versions are either **6.2 GA-6** or the current default download (version 7.x) available from the Liferay's website. I wish to integrate the latest Activiti Engine, the Activiti Explorer, upload the work-flow specifications and then execute them from within the Liferay Portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check [this solution](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/28884606)?

"This plugin allows users and admins to use Activiti BPMN workflow engine for publication process (for example instead of default Kaleo). It almost fully supports BPMN 2.0 specification and may fully replace Kaleo for executing publication processes."

Comment: Thanks for the solution (link), it worked for Liferay Portal CE 6.2 GA-6.